# Generate JSDoc for ES5-style methods?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am writing some JS scripts for a tiny JS interpreter that only supports ES5 and earlier syntax. For an object with methods, I can't use the "class" keyword, but can only do it in the following way:

```js
var my_object = {};
my_object.method_1 = function (...) {...}
```

I want to generate a document site for those scripts, so I added comments in JSDoc format:

```js
/**
 * this is my module
 */
var my_object = {};

/**
 * this is a method of my_object
 * @param {string} x blah blah
 */
my_object.method_1 = function (...) {...}
```

However, when I tried to generate docs by the command `npm run doc` (I created a package.json and a jsdoc.json with some content copied from the internet), the generated document only has `my_object` but the `method_1` is missing.

My question is if it is possible to properly include methods like the `method_1` in the generated doc site? (again, I cannot use new JS syntax)

Thank you so much. Let me know if you need any more information.

(The jsdoc installed in my env is 4.0.2)

Comment: You might want to consider writing modern JS and transpiling it with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: Try `var my_object = {method_1: function (...) {...}};`

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the comment. I tried this way before I posted the question. sorry for not mentioning it. but it works but not in a perfect way. I had to add a "@method <method-name> [description]" tag in the comment to let jsdoc pick it up. anyway, it's better than none at all.

Comment: @Quentin yeah, that is an approach. even if it complicates things but it should work anyway. thanks for the comment.